# "Непричастные (к) страданиям". Как определить, нужен ли предлог?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, управление

Пример: непричастные к страданиям людей, непричастные страданиям?
Как правильно? Как определить, нужен ли предлог?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно: **непричастные к страданиям людей.**

Правильность падежа и наличие предлога можно проверить по толковому словарю или по словарю "Управление в русском языке" на Грамоте.ру.

[http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=непричастный&all=x](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x)

НЕПРИЧАСТНЫЙ (непричастен) **к чему.** Он непричастен к этому преступлению; Он старался быть непричастным ко всему, что совершалось вокруг него.

Comment: То есть, определяем по вопросу? К чему или Чему?

Comment: По вопросу мы не определим наличие предлога (предположительно можно задать оба вопроса). Мы определяем, что это Д.п., но управление может быть предложным и беспредложным. И вот это нужно обязательно уточнить по словарю.

Comment: Любопытно, что согласно тому же словарю управления слово "причастен" раньше не требовал предлога. Сейчас это употребление устарело, но в книгах оно встречается. К слову "непричастен" это замечание тоже относится.

Comment: Где конкретно указано управление, не могу увидеть

Comment: Непричастный греху, например, это какой падеж?

Comment: Да, любопытно. Наверное, это можно как-то объяснить. Или задать вопрос:  почему управление стало предложным? Может быть, эта форма точнее по смыслу?

Comment: Агнец чистый, непорочный, непричастный греху ... [митрополит Антоний (Блум). О Евангельском благовестии (1974)] Вот это, наверное, устаревшая форма (беспредложный дательный).

Comment: Лия, в словаре указан предлог К в падежном вопросе К ЧЕМУ, это и есть указание на предложное управление дательным падежом..

Comment: Правильно ли я поняла, что слово непричастный всегда употребляется с предлогом к (ко)?  Если нет, дайте пример без предлога. Я не разбираюсь в падежном управлении. Т.е. в словаре смотреть по слову?

Comment: @Лия Вы поняли правильно: сейчас употребляется только с предлогом. В старину можно было и без, но примеры здесь не нужны — они Вас только запутают.

Answer (score 1):

Если посмотрим на слово ПРИЧАСТНЫЙ, то увидим, что беспредложное управление указано как устаревшее:

> [ПРИЧАСТНЫЙ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x) (причастен) к чему / (устар.) чему. Причастный к этому делу; В 1904 году была образована особая комиссия... с целью выдавать ссуды и пособия... лицам, причастным к искусству (Тел.); Я тому греху не причастен (М. Г.).

Очевидно, то же верно и для слова НЕПРИЧАСТНЫЙ. В Нацкорпусе есть несколько современных текстов, в которых слово НЕПРИЧАСТНЫЙ использовано без предлога. На мой взглад, это сделано для того, чтобы придать фразе "высокое" звучание. Возможно также, это осталось в религиозном и научном стиле.

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

> Мы уже умерли, сказал голос. И **непричастны живым**. Не входи, чтобы Арсений выжил. [Евгений Водолазкин. Лавр (2012)]
>
> При этом места лидеров занимают жанровые образования, обладающие свободными, открытыми структурами: предметом канонизации парадоксальным образом оказываются жанры неканонические, предпочтение отдается всему тому в литературе, что **непричастно формам** готовым, устоявшимся, стабильным. [В. Е. Хализев. Теория литературы (1999)]
>
> Однако и борьба с подобным врагом будет лишь в той мере святым подвигом, принятым Богом, в какой сердце защитников останется **непричастным злобе** и страстям самого агрессора. [А. И. Осипов. Православное видение войны и мира // Православная беседа, 1998]
>
> «Собственная природа» вещей **непричастна причинно-следственным отношениям**, а потому она находится за пределами мира явлений, в области вечных, неизменных сущностей, «приобщение» к которым невозможно. [История восточной философии (1998)]
>
> Сразу видно, что они **непричастны серьезной жизни** контингента, тех, кто пользуется кремлевской больницей и кремлевской столовой. [Ю. М. Нагибин. Дневник  (1983)]